# When is a noodle finished cooking

Tags: food-preservation

How do you tell when a noodle is done cooking? I have tried throwing it at the ceiling but I don't know if that works can someone please help me find out.

Comment: Just throw it against the side of the sink

Comment: May i know the kind(type) of noodles in question? (egg noodles, rice noodles etc)

Comment: It really depends on the noodle, but stickyness is not a sign of doneness, throwing a noodle at anything is not a test!

Answer (score 1):

I have heard about throwing it at the ceiling too, but not sure how that is supposed to work. It sounds a little bit too objective as a yes/no answer to "is it a good noodle?" Different people have slightly different ideas how well done they want their noodles. 
Simple to determine experimentally how long is perfect. As the noodles cook, just pull one out of the boiling water at frequent intervals and sample it. Be prepared to quickly drain the water off when the sample noodle reaches the level of doneness that you want. As soon as the noodles get to that point, act.  Drain off the water immediately, voila.

Comment: Once the noodles are done and water drained, you should wash the noodles under fresh water to get rid of excess starch.@Lorel

Comment: @SaurabhCooks rinsing is not always desirable.  For example, in the vast majority of Italian preparations, the pasta goes directly from the cooking water to the pan with the condiment.  Extra pasta water is added to emulsify the dish.

Comment: @moscafj Yeah I know which is why I have said "you should" and not "you must". It is all a personal choice.

Comment: @SaurabhCooks this is not intended to be snarky, but when I look up "should" in the dictionary, I see that it is intended to communicate an obligation.  If you suggest that "you should wash noodles under fresh water", it is read as a suggestion for standard practice.  I wanted to point out that there are cases where it should not be done.

Comment: Yes, I have already said in the last comment- "It is a personal choice"!

Answer (score 0):

While biting the noodles is always a good bet, you can also break the noodle open.  If you still see white starch in the center of the noodle, it needs more time, as it hasn't cooked all the way through, and will taste starchy.

Comment: ...unless you are looking to cook your noodle al dente, in which case there should be a slight color differentiation (less cooked) at the very center of your noodle.